# In app purchase, disable auto renew programmatically

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to figure out if is there any way to stop an auto renew in app purchase programmatically. I know that this can be achieve using the App Store dedicated area, but I would be interested in providing this chance to end user directly within the app.

I think this feature is not in place yet or am I missing something?

Comment: I'll give a try adding a radar request for this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that from application